# Good software to handle NTFS alternate data stream in windows explorer?

Tags: windows, ntfs, alternate-data-stream

I found one, but it seems to support XP only (I'm not sure) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csadsdetectorarticle.aspx

Do you know any alternate data stream plug-in or add-on for Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article explains ADS well, but most of the links no longer work: [dissecting-ntfs-hidden-streams](https://web.archive.org/web/20161012055240/http://www.forensicfocus.com/dissecting-ntfs-hidden-streams)

My top choice would be Microsoft's [Streams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams) utility. A good alternative with a graphical user interface is Nirsoft's [AlternateStreamView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/alternate_data_streams.html).

Comment: The article moved, screenshots are lost and most programs links are dead. https://www.forensicfocus.com/articles/dissecting-ntfs-hidden-streams/

Comment: Thanks @Arioch'The. Hopefully this updated answer is more useful.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best utilities I've found for working with ADS is [Streamarmor](http://www.securityxploded.com/streamarmor.php). It's standalone but has a lot functionality.

It's also freeware :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ streams -64

streams v1.60 - Reveal NTFS alternate streams.
Copyright (C) 2005-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

usage: streams [-s] [-d] <file or directory>
-s     Recurse subdirectories
-d     Delete streams
-nobanner
       Do not display the startup banner and copyright message.

$
```

Comment: what's `streams`? And how does it handle ADS **in explorer**? This isn't a good answer at all

Answer (score 0):

NoVirusThanks offers their [StreamDetector](http://www.novirusthanks.org/products/stream-detector/) package for free.

Microsoft also offers [Streams](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/streams.aspx) as part of the Windows Sysinternals package.

Both executables can be used without requiring installation, and both allow the automated removal of alternate data streams.

Answer (score 0):

One more GUI-based explorer:

- http://hex.pp.ua/ntfs-stream-explorer.php ( more of desciption )
- http://hex.pp.ua/ntfs-stream-explorer-eng.php ( short but in English )

E-SET seems to be fuzzy about safety of it though.

- http://virusscan.jotti.org/filescanjob/zt1smrhnz4
- http://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/75722cb18886e4b6501eb495d77a5e8a4c9e0f0203e966b4440768a60b56fe93  (but it was "all green" 10 months ago)

---

If one uses Unreal Commander or Total Commander (or maybe there are more WFX-aware file managers) then also https://totalcmd.net/plugring/NTFSFileStreams2.html